# how do I add 'min' and 'max' column in a table of descriptive statistics in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I've just started using R in my first year of uni and I'm having a lot of issues. For this task I'm trying to usw Rmarkdown. I'm trying to produce a table of descriptive statistics which include observations, mean, SD, Min, and Max but I can't seem to add the last two.

```
Sierra_Leone_Trunc <- select(Sierra_Leone, civilian_deaths, ethnic_pol, id_lntroop, ln_pop, ln_ppp, capdist, nlights_calib_mean, diamprim_y, prior_violence, excluded)
kable(describe(Sierra_Leone_Trunc))
kable(describe(Sierra_Leone_Trunc, skew = F, ranges = F), digits = 3, caption = "Table 1. Descriptive Statistics")
```

I got my variables and when I use `kable(describe())` I get a table of ALL the stats, but when I remove skew and ranges it removes everything except 'vars', 'n', 'mean', 'sd', 'se'.

How do I get the right statistics I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with `describe` (I assume from `psych` package) and not with `kable` or rmd.

In `describe`, when you include `ranges = F` it does not include range statistics, which include min, max, and range.

Here is one approach that might allow for flexibility and clarity. You didn't include what packages you're using, but this will work with `psych` and `dplyr` (noticing you used `select`). I will use `mtcars` data.frame as an example.

First, select which variables from you data.frame you want your summary statistics on. Then, use `describe` (and if skewness/kurtosis are not needed, can use `skew = F`). Then, select the summary statistics you want, such as `n`, `mean`, `sd`, `min`, and `max`. Then pass to `kable`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>%
  describe(skew = F) %>%
  select(n, mean, sd, min, max) %>%
  kable()
```